# Echo cart with the number of quantity of items that are added to cart

Tags: php, cart

I have been following a ecom web tutorial and I have been changing the code many times but still did not get it right.The problem is to change the number that echo next to the cart based on quantity of product instead of product id.

**image example:**
[image]

Shop.php code:

```
<a href="#tab2">CART <span class="badge">
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
        echo count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
    } else {
        echo '0';}
?>
</span></a>
```

action.php code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["product_id"])) {
    $order_table = '';
    $message = '';
    if ($_POST["action"] == "add") {
        if (isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
            $is_available = 0;
            foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {
                if ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST["product_id"]) {
                    $is_available++;
                    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] + $_POST["product_quantity"];
                }
            }
            if ($is_available < 1) {
                $item_array = array(
                    'product_id'        => $_POST["product_id"],
                    'product_name'      => $_POST["product_name"],
                    'product_price'     => $_POST["product_price"],
                    'product_quantity'  => $_POST["product_quantity"]
                );
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
            }
       } else {
            $item_array = array(
                'product_id'        => $_POST["product_id"],
                'product_name'      => $_POST["product_name"],
                'product_price'     => $_POST["product_price"],
                'product_quantity'  => $_POST["product_quantity"]
            );
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this a Magento cart? I see it's in your tag and people are answering with Magento answers, but if you are getting this from a Magento tutorial, I would maybe look for a new tutorial, this is not the conventional way to deal with the Magento cart. If not a Magento cart, remove that tag so you don't get Magento-specific answers, they will be irrelevant to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the quantities from each item from the cart using a loop:

```
function getCartQty()
    {
        # If there is nothing in the cart, return 0
        if(empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart']))
            return 0;
        # Store array
        $qty = array();
        # Loop items in cart
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $item){
            # Store the quantity of each item
            $qty[] =  $item['product_quantity'];
        }
        # Return the sum
        return array_sum($qty);
    }
?>
<a href="#tab2">CART <span class="badge"><?php echo getCartQty() ?></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`count()` is going to return the number of elements in an array. When run on your shopping cart array stored in the $_SESSION array, you're counting the number of unique products.

As each product has a quantity value, you need to retrieve the sum of those. Here's a function you can use to perform that calculation:

```
function my_shopping_cart_total_product_count() {
    $product_count = 0;

    if ( isset( $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] ) ) {
        $product_count = array_sum( array_column( $_SESSION['shopping_cart'], 'product_quantity' ) );
    } 

    return $product_count;
}
```

In the example above I'm using `array_column` to get an array containing all of the product quantities. I'm then running that through `array_sum` to get the total. You could of course simply use a foreach loop.

**Usage:**

```
<a href="#tab2">CART <span class="badge"><?php echo my_shopping_cart_total_product_count(); ?></span></a>
```

**Documentation:**

- array_sum - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php
- array_column - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

**Additional notes:**

The code in action.php is quite concerning. There appears to be a lack of user input sanitization. I'd recommend researching data sanitization in order to improve security.

Answer (score 0):

You can change settings in Magento backend to get total quantity of items instead of quantity of different products:

1. System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout.
2. My Cart Link > Display Cart Summary.
3. Set this to: Display number of items in cart.

This works on default Magento theme so you could make it work for your own theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
# return shopping cart items count means how many sku add to shopping cart
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemCount()

# return shopping cart items summary (suppose you add sku1 6 qty and sku2 3 qty = total 9 qty return)
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount()
```

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/23496/46249

<sup>*Note: Do not use `$_SESSION` in Magento, there are alternative methods.*</sup>